# Select the salary of the higher-paid employees of the manager

Tags: sql, linq

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP ( 
EmpNo INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
Ename NVARCHAR(350), 
JOB NVARCHAR(100), 
Mgr INT, HireDate DATETIME, 
Sal INT, 
Comm INT, 
DeptNo INT )
```

I want to select the salary of the higher-paid employees of the manager.

Here's my code:

```
from a in EMPs
where ((from b in EMPs where b.Mgr != null 
select  b.Sal + (b.Comm != null ? b.Comm :0))) > (select c in EMPs where c.Mgr == null 
select  b.Sal +(b.Comm != null ? b.Comm :0))
select a.Ename
```

Please! help me.

Comment: And your question is?  Does it not work?  Does it give the wrong answer?  An error?

Comment: Please little bit more clear. Please do not post half question. This is really bad. you just come and ask meaningless things whats the use of this.

Comment: Oh! my fault. It's doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide some sample data (SQL records or may be a SQL fiddle) and show what is your current output and what is your expected output ?

Comment: i have this table  
CREATE TABLE EMP (
 EmpNo INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Ename NVARCHAR(350),
 JOB NVARCHAR(100),
 Mgr INT,
 HireDate DATETIME,
 Sal INT,
 Comm INT,
 DeptNo INT 
)
i want select the higher-paid employees of the manager his salary

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for all those Employees who are paid the highest salary under each Manager. If that is the case, Try this:-

```
var query = employees.GroupBy(x => x.ManagerName)
                                 .Select(x => new { ManagerName = x.Key,EmployeeName = x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Salary + (z.Comm ?? 0)).First().EmpName });
```

**Step 1**: Group By ManagerName
**Step 2**: Select ManagerName (Which will be Key after grouping), From each group fetch the highest paid employee by ordering in descending order and selecting the first employee.

Where i have used this Type:-

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public string ManagerName { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public int? Comm { get; set; }
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j5JTD9).

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained the code.

Comment: @Tim - As i mentioned before the code, I am considering OP need all those employees who have highest salary and who works under same manager.

Comment: Sure, I got that.  What I'm saying is that little explanation of the LINQ statement could help people down the road who come across the answer.